# Problem with syncing contact list with double email columns

Tags: list, email, outlook, sync

Outlook has standard fields for home email, work email, home phone, work phone, mobile phone etc.
We would like all these fields to be available at the SharePoint as well and be sync with outlook.
The Problem is only two phone numbers and one email address are synced by now.
I think the problem is outlook cant sync a contact list from SharePoint 2010 with two email columns, it sync only one, the second email column does not sync, and the third phone number

[image: Double email picture]

Haven't got a clue, so help me here guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*edit

Add a field to the list titled User Name, with a field type of Person or Group, and select Account from the Show field: dropdown.

Create a SharePoint Designer workflow to update the list when an item is added or changed.

- workflow settings - update the Start Options to start when an item is created and changed.
- put your cursor inside of Step 1 and type **set** then select Set Field in Current Item.
- click on **field** and select your e-mail field.
- click on **value** and select User Name and select Email Address from the Return field as: drop down.
- Publish the workflow and test it.

Comment: Well, It's a small organization so we update this Contact list manually.
I know the default Contact's list does not have two email fields, we add one more manually because it didn't work with one email field and ';' or ',' the result was syncing only the first email address on the field. ( hope it was understandable)

Comment: Updated my first post, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: (The first user was unregistered so I have no other choice here, and I cant find the way to PM the moderator) Hey eHaze Thanks for the answer, I'm not quite sure what you meant in your answer, could you please upload a photo of the workflow from the sharepoint designer, I cant manage to create such workflow